How do I avoid nails at the keyhole slot with Hardie Board Straight Shingles?
Homeowner here. We are replacing old cedar siding. We are using Hardie Board Straight Shingles 4' x 15". I got the first course in and realize as I place more, there is a chance a nail will fall through the keyhole slot. Am I missing something to secure these better? Is there a technique to deal with this?

By "keyhole slot" do you mean the gap between shingles at the upper portion? What do you mean "fall through"?
